# SVN search in files content?

Tags: svn

Any possibility to look for a keyword in files through the svn repository?

I have a SSDT project with many .sql files, need to search through the file's for a certain keyword within the .sql file. Is this even possible to get a list of commits which contained the specific keyword ?

Thanks in advance,
Best Regards

Comment: There are several ways: a very simple one would be to export a specific revision, search through the files, remember the findings and continue with next revision

Comment: Maybe `svn blame` would be useful.